# Why isn't my auth middleware called in Nuxt 3?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I created a root directory called middleware and added a file called auth.ts.
This is the code inside just for testing:

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async (to, from) => {
    console.log('middleware/auth')
    console.log('to', to)
    console.log('from', from)

    return navigateTo('/')
  })
```

Then in the page I added this:

```
<script setup>
definePageMeta({
    middleware: [
        'auth'
    ]
})
</script>
```

When I access this page I don't see any logs. Is there a step I am missing ?

Comment: Have you tried removing the async keyword in defineNuxtRouteMiddleware ? I don't see any example in the docs using an async function

Comment: remove `async`. middleware not accept Promise

Comment: @TachibanaShin It wraps around vue router which supports promises in Vue 3 https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/blob/main/packages/nuxt/src/app/composables/router.ts#L43 . And any way, it should have been called regardless of return type, while it's stated that console.log is not called

Comment: it; s working now, actually it was a mistake where I declared :/